# investigate uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)$ = $\frac{(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

investigate uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)$ = $\frac{(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$.

i am asked to investigate uniform convergence of the sequence of functions provided about. should I use Weierstrass M-Test?
I know that If $x$ $\neq$ 0, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$ = $x$ ($pointwise$ $limit$)

Comment: Weierstrass M doesn't really work here, since the functions are not sums. You say you know the pointwise limit (let's call it $f$), so you can see if the maximum of the function $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$ for any $x$. If it does, then you're sequence converges uniformly, and if it doesn't, then the sequence doesn't converge uniformly.

Comment: so you are saying take the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} | f_{n}(x) - f(x) | $ as n approaches infinity? take the limit twice?

Comment: this is what I have so far

Comment: For any $\varepsilon$ $>$ 0. Since $f_{n}$ $\rightarrow$ $x$ uniformly on $(-\infty,-\varepsilon]$ $\bigcup$ $[\varepsilon,\infty)$, 
\\


$|$$x$ - $\frac{(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
= $|$$x$$\frac{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$ 
- $\frac{(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
=
$|$$\frac{x + n^{2}x^{3} - [(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}]}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
=
$|$$\frac{x + n^{2}x^{3} - [nx + x + n^{2}x^{3}]}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
\\

=
$|$$\frac{-nx}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
= 
$\frac{nx}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$.

Comment: Not exactly. You want to take $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$So if you compute $\frac{d}{dx}(f_n(x)-f(x))$, then you can obtain the $x_0$ coordinate of the maximum of $f_n$ in terms of $n$. Then you see if $|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|$ goes to zero.

Comment: still confused..i feel like the derivative is unnecessary

Comment: i'd rather show using epsilon

Comment: $|$$x$ - $\frac{(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
= $|$$x$$\frac{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$ 
- $\frac{(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
=
$|$$\frac{x + n^{2}x^{3} - [(n+1)x + n^{2}x^{3}]}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
=
$|$$\frac{x + n^{2}x^{3} - [nx + x + n^{2}x^{3}]}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
\\

=
$|$$\frac{-nx}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$$|$
= 
$\frac{nx}{1 + n^{2}x^{2}}$
$<$
$\frac{nx}{n^{2}x^{2}}$
$\leq$
$\frac{1}{nx}$
$\leq$
$\frac{1}{n}$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ which goes to zero as n goes to $\infty$

Comment: why cant i do this

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{nx}\leq \frac{1}{n\varepsilon}$?

Comment: Also, I will tell you now: the sequence does not converge uniformly. See my answer, in which I leave the final step for you to do (you will see that the maximum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ does not go to zero).

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestions in my comments, we can solve this problem by seeing if the maximum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$. As you have pointed out, the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n)$ is the identity function. Hence,
$$f_n(x)-f(x)=\frac{(n+1)x+n^2x^3}{1+n^2x^2}-x=\frac{nx+x+n^2x^3-x-n^2x^3}{1+n^2x^2}=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f_n(x)-f(x))=\frac{(1+n^2x^2)(n)-(nx)(2n^2x)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}=\frac{n(1-n^2x^2)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$$
Therefore, if the critical points of $f_n-f$ occur at $x_0$, then we have
$$\frac{n(1-n^2x_0^2)}{(1+n^2x_0^2)^2}=0\iff x_0=\pm\frac{1}{n}$$
Hence, it suffices to show $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left|f_n\left(\pm\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(\pm\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|=0$ to show uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$. Or, if $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left|f_n\left(\pm\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(\pm\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|\neq 0$, then we do not have uniform convergence.

**Addendum:** In case there is any confusion with this technique used to determine uniform convergence, let me explain. In order to see if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, we can equivalently see if the maximum distance between $f_n$ and $f$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$. This is precisely what the computation $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ does: if this limit is zero then the maximum distance between $f_n$ and $f$ goes to zero (so we have uniform convergence), but if this limit is nonzero, then there is always some distance between the functions (so we cannot have uniform convergence).

Comment: you mean "Or if, .... $\neq$ 0 then we do not have uniform convergence

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had it right originally and made some edits and must have made a typo.

Comment: excellent. it was $\frac{1}{2}$. so it is not uniformly convergent. I believe this is also because the rate of convergence is not the same for all pointwise limits

Comment: if we look at the graph

Comment: Yes this is what I got as well. Indeed, if we graph the functions $f_n$ for some values of $n$ (which I always recommend to do, especially if you have access to graphing technology) we see that there is always some distance between $f_n$ and $f$, which does not shrink to zero as $n$ increases. So we cannot have uniform convergence.